# Why only one view is added to the fragment layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So i am trying to add as many "players" i have in my database, just their name. (Below i just used a simple for loop and removed code that calls data from database) My problem is that when i try to add `card_player.xml` to the `fragment_layout.xml` in a for loop it just adds only the first item and i don't know why. The below it just shows a card view with "0" as `mName`. Shouldn't it show 5 card views?

> fragment_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mPlayerList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

> card_player.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/rippelColor"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Dummy Name" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my fragment.java onCreate method :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
initView();
return rootView;


}
public void initView(){
    LinearLayout mLinearLayoutContainer = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mPlayerList);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_of_player, mLinearLayoutContainer, false);

        TextView mName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.mName);

        mName.setText(i+""); // just set as name the i variable.

        mLinearLayoutContainer.addView(mView);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cardLayout has matchParent for height so the first one is ocupping all the screen. If you add an ScrollView as parent of your LinearLayout, you will see the other ones above.

The corrected code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/rippelColor"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Dummy Name" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ...damn.. how did i miss that. Thanks i'll accept the answer when i am available.